# Is there a working sample for the Android 1.5 VideoView/MediaPlayer class?

Tags: java, android, android-widget, media

I'm new to Android dev.

There's a very pretty state diagram of the [MediaPlayer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html), but I can't for the life of me figure out how to actually use this class to play a video.

There's a view samples around the 'net, but they seem to be for previous versions of the SDK.
I've also checked the [official samples](http://developer.android.com/guide/samples/index.html), but with no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. There is example code for VideoView and MediaPlayer in:

```
<android-sdk>/platforms/android-1.5/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/media/
```

These aren't linked anywhere in the online help, as the samples there are out of sync with what is actually shipped.

Edit: Note the samples exist, but they don't work in Android 1.5, see this [bug](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=2570&q=videoview&colspec=ID%20Type%20Version%20Security%20Status%20Owner%20Summary).